# Delete duplicates in ListViewItem C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need a way to delete all duplicated rows that have a duplicated `DisplayName`

```
foreach (XElement item in this.items)
{
    this.lstEmployees.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(new string[] 
            {
                item.Element("Initials") != null ? item.Element("Initials").Value : "",
                item.Element("DisplayName") != null ? item.Element("DisplayName").Value : "",
                item.Element("Dep_Name") != null ? item.Element("Dep_Name").Value : "",
                item.Element("Phoneext") != null ? item.Element("Phoneext").Value : "",
                item.Element("Privatephone") != null ? item.Element("Privatephone").Value : ""
            })
        {
            Tag = item
        });
```

i didn't write the code i just got the task to delete rows with names that has been repeated, ( it only goes again because some members have more than one department)

Comment: Why you are adding it to the ListVIew if you don't need it. I would check if `item.Element("DisplayName")` is not in list then Add it. Anyway to delete duplicates [How to delete duplicate items in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6011152/4018834)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete duplicate items in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011116/how-to-delete-duplicate-items-in-listview)

Comment: i didn't write the code i just got the task to delete rows with names that has been repeated, ( it only goes again because some members have more than one department)

Comment: You can try to use DistinctBy() and pick distinct property : foreach (XElement item in this.items.DistinctBy(x=>x.Name))

Comment: i tried this foreach (XElement item in this.items.DistinctBy(x => x.Elements("Initials") but it dosen't quite work

Comment: Have you tried foreach (XElement item in this.items.DistinctBy(x => x.Elements("DisplayName"") ?  Several people might have the same initials. You might also want a distinct combination of both "DisplayName" and say "PhoneNumber" in case you have more than person with the same name.

Comment: i've also tried with displayname yes, and every initial is different within our company so no worries there.